# (JAVA) Erro ao retornar quantidade de registro usando o COUNT do SQL

Tags: java, sql

Estou tentando retorna a quantidade de registro de uma tabela, nessa tabela tenho atualmente 6 registros porém minha Query retorna apenas um, como se houvesse apenas um registro. Preciso que retorne a quantidade total, 6 registros.

> Query que utilizei no SQL e deu certo

```
SELECT COUNT ([num_item])
FROM tb_temp_prod;
```

> Query no JAVA

```
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;

        Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER).newInstance();
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

        stmt = conn.createStatement();

        ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) AS num_item FROM tb_temp_prod");

            while(result.next()){
             result.getInt("num_item"); 
             //result.getInt(1); Já tentei assim também e não deu certo.

            }

        System.out.println("Total: " + result);
```

> Resultado: Total: SQLServerResultSet:1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**

> Resolvido:

**

```
ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) AS num_item FROM tb_temp_prod");

            while(result.next()){

             int teste = result.getInt("num_item");
             System.out.println("Total: " + teste);

            }
```

Comment: O tratamento `result.getInt(1);` é desnecessário.

Comment: Perfeito, obrigado. Testei aqui e funcionou sem. TKS @AugustoVasques